# Округлить десятичное число до 5 или 0 в JS

Tags: javascript

Имею массив коефициентов с букмекерских контор где всегда 2 знака после запятой

```
var odds = [1.83, 1.68, 2.23, 1.17, ...];
```

как округдить второе чило после запятой
до **0** если это **0, 1, 2, 3, 4** или до **5** если это **5, 6, 7, 8, 9**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.floor(n * 20) / 20`?

Comment: Исправил `round` на `floor`, так вроде правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть более психованный вариант, выводит сразу с нолями)

```js
function oddMaker (arr) {
   arr.forEach (function (element, key) {
    var str = arr[key].toString();
    var subKey = str.substr(3);
    var subOdd = Number(subKey);
    if (subOdd>5) {
     element = str.substr(0, str.length-1) + "5";
     arr[key] = Number(element);
    } else {
     element = str.substr(0, str.length-1) + "0";
     arr[key] = element;
    }
   }    
   );
   return arr;
  }
  
  oddMaker(odds);
  console.log(odds.length);
  for (var k = 0; k < odds.length; k++) {
   console.log (odds[k] + "\n");
```

Выводит такое:

```js
1.80

1.65

2.20

1.15
```